# Search through a json array obtained from a database

Tags: php, arrays, json

First of all: Yes i did check other answers but they sadly didn't do the trick.

So i'm currently working on a script that checks if an email exists in the database. So the database data is obtained through a webservice and with an input filter function the following `JSON` object is returned:

```
{"customers":{"customer":{"lastname":"test","firstname":"login","email":"nielsvanenckevort@hotmail.com"}}}
```

Now i would like to check if the email is filled in correctly. I'm using a `foreach()` statement to compare the values but i'm always getting a `not found` returned. Maybe someone here is able to find the mistake i've made. So the full code is shown down below.

```
$resultEmail = ($webService->get( $optUser ));

$emailResult = json_encode($resultEmail);
$emailArray = json_decode($resultEmail);

echo ($emailResult);
echo ($chopEmail);
foreach($emailArray->customers->customer as $item)
{
    if($item->email == $email)
    {
        echo "found it!";
    }
}

// The $optUser is the JSON object
```

Comment: `$emailResult` is a json object. You can not use it in array.

Comment: @jeroen php will execute a `foreach` if an `StdClass` is passed to it

Comment: @WilliamPerron You're right, and not only `StdClass` it seems...

Comment: Why do you use json_encode on the json before you use json_decode? Wouldn't that give the original result? Also the returned string looks a bit strange, you have an object customers with an object customer, not with an array of customer objects

Comment: @rypskar Yeah i'm aware of that but that's how the database of prestashop is build. Can't do much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the quickest way would be [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function, so you can use it this way

```
function hasEmail($string, $email)
{
    return strpos($string, $email) !== false;
}

//example
echo hasEmail($resultEmail, $email) ? 'Has email' : 'Email not found';
```

Comment: Great! I already took a look at `strpos()` but at first it didn't work. Now it does, thank you for your explanation and answer!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to decode the string as an associative array instead of a json object, and then check if the key `email` exists using the [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function.

```
// passing true to json_decode will make it return an array
$emailArray = json_decode($resultEmail, true);

foreach($emailArray['customers'] as $customer) {
    if(array_key_exists('email', $customer)) {
        echo 'Found it!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mistake come from the foreach loop. You should write it this way :

```
foreach($emailArray->customers as $customer) {
    if($customer->email == $email) {
        echo "found it!";
    }
}
```

Please note that $emailArray is not an array but an object when you don't set the second parameter of the json_decode function :

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
$array = json_decode($data,true);
```